# getting error "Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicExistsException: Topic "ticktock2.time" already exists"

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

While deploying the basic stream, gets error topic already exists

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicExistsException: Topic "ticktock2.time" already exists

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that there could be race condition when the apps are deployed and the apps trying to create the topic as they are being deployed.

Which deployer do you use? For instance, in case of `local` deployer, it spins off a new process for each app and it is possible that one of the apps creates a topic (the common destination name for the source/sink) while the other fails to create as the topic already exists.

Do you see this behaviour consistently every time you deploy the stream?

Comment: It looks like this issue is fixed here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/83. Can you try checking the Spring Cloud Stream Kafka binder version above 1.2.0.M2 ?

Comment: i was trying local server... The error disappeared automatically after few tries.. thank you..